# Error getting change properties with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, change-tracking

I'm using entity framework and I need to know which field of a table has been modified so I wrtote this code

```
IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
        {
            if (stateEntryEntity.Entity != null)
            {
                var stateEntry = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
                IEnumerable<string> modifiedProperties = stateEntry.GetModifiedProperties(); 
            }
        }
```

the problem is that instead of getting only the changed field I get all the fields of the modified object.

Any idea of why I have this strange behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: What is `this` in the code?